# How can this distance on the wing be calculated?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

To calculate a wing's Mean Aerodynamic Chord MAC, I need the length of the line in blue in this image:

[image]

How can I calculate this distance?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a math (trig) question & not about aviation, the background image notwithstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the part of the diagram above the blue line.

Assuming that the trailing edge at the wing root is at right angles
to the fuselage,
then 6.5 and 23.5 and trigonometry tell you everything about the triangle
that is like a delta wing whose root lies on the midline of the fuselage.

Now you know the length of the delta wing's trailing edge.
So use similar triangles.
Divide 5.6 by the length of the TE.

Multiply that by 6.5 to get the blue line's length.

(Or just use a ruler.  The diagram's numbers are only to two significant figures!)

Comment: mmm I don´t  understand all

Comment: Similar triangles? I don´t see the geometry that two triangles

Comment: Make the delta wing.  Then you have the first triangle within which you make the similar triangle.

Answer (score -1):

If you can assume the sweep angle is constant from root, then

6.5  - 5.6 * sin(23.5) = **4.26**

Comment: if you don't explain what's happening, this answer is essentially useless, as it does not actually help to understand.